# How to implement searching?

Tags: search, search-engine, google-search-api, search-engine-api

we are trying to add searching to our web site and want this search function to search only a few things:

- Files - Obviously we need to parse the text of PDF, PPT and DOC files in our case
- User comments. Users will be available to comment on the stuff and we want to catch if some user is searching for that relative information

I would like to have your advices on how to develop such a system. Should we get an external search system such as Google's or just install an open source one or develop a new one from scratch.

Thanks.

Comment: Hope this might help u: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7399654/searching-for-file-extension-in-entire-system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this one: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/

Comment: There is a solr client for .net http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/